# How to resolve or bypass OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache2

For a university project I set up a server Apahe2 with SSL, self signed certificate and openssl-1.0.2g because I need a RC4+RSA CipherSuite.
The server work properly (I know that the server works properly because I tried to reach the site from an old browser and it works) but when from a client (with openssl-1.0.2g too and the file host edited with the correct association IP server - CommonName) I try to do a wget command with my site as parameter I get the error "**OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure**" despite I have installed my self signed certificate of the server on client.
Anyone please can help me with this issue?

Comment: This is not an error which can be "bypassed". It is not the typical certificate error where the client can just decide to continue anyway. The exact reason for this error is unknown though, i.e. it might be mismatch in ciphers, unexpected `server_name` or some configuration error. It's impossible to tell just from this error message alone. Look at the servers error log for more clues on what it might be.

Comment: The problem is relative ciphers suite, I need RC4 for the project but libssl-dev 1.1 doesn't support ciphers with RC4, I tried to set `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "RC4-SHA,RC4-MD5,@SECLEVEL=0");` but doesn't work (with this code all ciphers were removed in the CLIENT HELLO). Anyone has ideas on how force to use ciphers with RC4?

Comment: RC4 is by default not compiled into OpenSSL 1.1.1. You would need to compile your own version of OpenSSL with RC4 included and also link it to the binaries like wget.

Comment: Thanks so much for the very fast answer. There is a guide to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.md#enable-weak-ssl-ciphers

Comment: I have already a version of OpenSSL that support RC4 (if i run the command `openssl ciphers` I see ciphers with RC4), I need that libssl-dev1.1.1 will support ciphers with RC4 because when I try to connect to server (that support already RC4) by code in the CLIENT HELLO there are no RC4 ciphers and if I try to force libssl-dev by `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "RC4-SHA,RC4-MD5,@SECLEVEL=0");`, any ideas on how do that? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that the openssl you use with `openssl ciphers` is using the exact same libssl as the one you try to use in your code? You might check with `ldd`.

Comment: I checked and openssl has no libssl dependency, while my code builded has libssl.so.1.1 as dependecy. I need that this libssl.so.1.1 supports ciphers with RC4, any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Again, you need to  your own version which supports RC4 and you need to link your tools against it. Obviously this is not done yet, i.e. your openssl build which supports RC4 is not the same one which is used by your own program.

Comment: Can you provide the url so we can test it? Without that it's kind of a shot in the dark.

Answer (score -2):

This is a duplicate of my question here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/590776/3285

---

The answer that you want though is

```
curl --ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

That should solve it for you.